# QR code reader for Android 10 and better

Tags: gratis, android, qr-code

I've been using the old [XZing barcode scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en_SG&gl=US). It's been a workhorse for almost as long as I've been using Android but with Android 10 and 11 I've had... odd issues like the app being stuck upside down.

There's *heavy* use of QR for Covid 19 related temperature and contract tracing check-ins here so having an upside down barcode scanner is a major annoyance, even if one can read upside down...

So my requirements are

- Runs *reliably* on Android 10 or 11.
- Scans QR codes.
- Ideally as simple as possible (I need to upgrade mom's phone), or I should have options to remove things like metadata and such. I just need a link or text out, and click on the link to open it in the browser.
- Free (gratis), no ads and on the Google app store.

Comment: Sure you don't have a typo there in your last condition? Mustn't it read "free, no ads and available at F-Droid"? Because then I'd suggest you my favorite one: SecScanQR. Though I need to test it on Android 10 first to be able to confirm "reliable" first-hand.

Comment: Google app store - fdroid is nice for techie folks but this is for   a muggle

Comment: Muggles are much safer at F-Droid, they usually don't know the spells to defend themselves against the dark arts played at G. ‎

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've switched to Binary Eye [google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.markusfisch.android.binaryeye) [fdroid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.markusfisch.android.binaryeye/)

- Runs reliably on android 10 or 11
  Tested it on both
- Scans QR codes
  Tested it in practice
- Ideally as simple as possible
  The default is to show metadata and a hex dump. You can turn this off in preferences, so if you're setting this up for someone else you can turn it off in the preferences
- Free in both senses of the word, and on both the google and fdroid app stores.

Comment: Picked cause this was the one I went with. I'll be resting out the other options as time permits and comment on whether I have the same issues

Answer (score 0):

There is a Plus version of Barcode Scanner: [Barcode Scanner+ (Plus)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android) which is now free [as stated here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26065426). It seems to work very well although I tried it on android 9 and not on android 10 or 11

Can you please better explain what you mean with  `stuck upside down`

Comment: It ignores the orientation of the phone and is was stuck upside down, so the top of the screen was the bottom of the scanning window. This... adversely affected by ability to use it. It worked fine on 9, hence the explicit requirement for 10

Comment: In App settings there is a checkbox `No auto rotation` (Translation could not be accurate as my installation is in Italian) which is checked by default. Unchecking it, lets the screen follow the orientation

Answer (score 0):

[LEADTOOLS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=leadtools.barcodedemo) has a barcode reader available on the Google Play Store.  It contains no ads and is available at no cost, can handle multiple barcode symbologies including QR, and should run on Android 10.  (Functioned as expected on my mobile using that version).  The output is just the decoded text.

Note:  I work for the company which created this app.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SecScanQR now for years without problems in Android 8.1.0.
It is also available in the F-Droid AppStore.
https://f-droid.org/de/packages/de.t_dankworth.secscanqr/

Comment: I already mentioned that in a comment on the question, Bruno. So did you use it for years **on Android 10 or 11** – as that's what the OP asks for? That was the missing part and why I only posted a comment instead of an answer. Could you please **[edit]** your answer to include that – plus the link to the app at F-Droid?

Comment: I would like to live in a world, where my three year old phone had Android 11. But sadly I don't.

Comment: Oh my last phone (a oneplus 5T) started with... 7 and went up to 10 stock. Its about that old :)

Comment: Ah, was afraid of that. Should finally get SecScanQR on my FP2, too. Works fine for me on 7 & 8, but as pointed out I had no time trying it on 10. Now the camera module was replaced, I finally could…

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the **SecUSo Privacy Friendly QR Scanner** for years, it works great on both Android 10 and Android 11.

Get it the way you prefer:

- https://github.com/SecUSo/privacy-friendly-qr-scanner
- https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.secuso.privacyFriendlyCodeScanner
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.secuso.privacyFriendlyCodeScanner

License: Free & open source, GPLv3

[image]